# ElasticSearch Play-1.2 Module not working in Client Mode

Tags: search, module, playframework, elasticsearch, playframework-1.x

I am using the Elasticsearch Play module in a play application and have only had half success. I am able to configure and use it  in local/embedded mode. I am however not able to run in client mode.

I set up the elasticsearch service on the same box on which my play application is hosted. I added the following to my app config:

**#ELASTIC SEARCH MODULE**

```
elasticsearch.local=false
elasticsearch.client=localhost:9200
```

I am running in DEV mode. I have also tried connecting to a remote host with no success. In both cases, when I make the first request to the application, it starts loading various modules and just hangs when it tries to connect to the elasticsearch service. Here's a snippet from my logs:

```
[TIME: 2013-08-09 19:59:09] [LOG LEVEL: DEBUG]  MorphiaPlugin-1.2.12> reading configuration<BR>
[TIME: 2013-08-09 19:59:15] [LOG LEVEL: INFO]   Connected to memcached <BR>
[TIME: 2013-08-09 19:59:15] [LOG LEVEL: INFO]   Connecting Play! to Elastic Search in Client Mode<BR>
**[TIME: 2013-08-09 19:59:15]   [LOG LEVEL: INFO]   Transport Client - Host: localhost Port: 9200**
```

**Edit**
Connecting to port 9300 works. However elasticsearch throws a **java.io.StreamCorruptedException** as soon as I attempt to  connect. here is a snippet of the stack trace:

```
[2013-08-14 09:44:29,405][WARN ][transport.netty] [Kl'rt] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x30ec6e1f, /192.168.10.126:45148 => /192.168.10.126:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:27)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you using the play2-elasticsearch module? There is a play-elasticsearch module for before Play 2, but I am assuming you are referring to the play2-elasticsearch module.

If you are using play2-elasticsearch, have you tried elasticsearch.client="localhost:**9300**"? The README.md in play2-elasticsearch's github repository uses port 9300 in its example, which is the transport port used by Elasticsearch, as described here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/transport/.

Comment: I am using the play 1.2.x elasticsearch module. I have tried connecting using port 9300. From what I have observed, it fails to connect to the server but continues to load the application. Any attempt to index fails and throws a NoNodeAvailableException.

Comment: Ahh... I have no experience with the play 1.2.x elasticsearch module. If you can make the switch to play2-elasticsearch, it might be to your benefit, as play 1.x is no longer supported.